# Ways of adding nodes in a normal binary tree

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

Take the following binary tree as an example. Let's say we wanted to add some node (the value associated isn't important). Where can we add the node?

[image]

In the picture below, I know I can add nodes at the end of the tree (like the green one I drew). But can we also add nodes in the middle of a certain edge (like the red ones I drew)?

[image]

I know this isn't true for a Binary Search Tree, but what about a normal Binary Tree? Also, if the answer is affirmative, is there another way of adding nodes in a normal Binary Tree?

Thanks for any help in advance! (and I am sorry about my drawing skills)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we also add nodes in the middle of a certain edge (like the red ones I drew)?

Yes, the edge splits into two edges, where the inserted node will just have one child.

> I know this isn't true for a Binary Search Tree, but what about a normal Binary Tree?

It could sometimes work out for a binary search tree too, but it wouldn't be good practice, as it leads more quickly to an unbalanced tree than the normal insertion procedure would lead to.

> is there another way of adding nodes in a normal Binary Tree?

You can also make the new node the root of the binary tree, and its only child would be the old root.